# Why Regex doen’t gives the longest match?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I’ve regex  `a(boy)?(boycott)?` testing against `aboycott`.

```js
const result = "aboycott".match(/a(boy)?(boycott)?/);

console.log(result[0]);
```

My thought process

- `a` matches with `a`
- `b` matches with `b`
- `o` matches with `o`
- `y` matches with `y`
- **`c` doesn't matches with `b`**

*Since (boy) is optional so its state is saved and the REGEX engine can backtrack to try the saved state*

- `b` matches with `b`
- `o` matches with `o`
- `y` matches with `y`
- `c` matches with `c`
- `o` matches with `o`
- `t` matches with `t`
- `t` matches with `t`

The final match should be `aboycott` but it matches `aboy`. What is going on here? If I'm not wrong `?` is greedy it first tries to match and the state is saved. If there is no match then backtrack to the saved place.

Comment: ? is matches one or more, maybe you want * (zero or more).

Comment: It does match, it matched `aboy` and so it doesn't match the rest. Maybe you meant to do: `"aboycott".match(/a(boy)?(cott)?/);` ?

Comment: `boy` is a prefix of `boycott`. After matching `boy`, there is no way to match `boycott` as there is only `cott` left to match. If you swap them, you will match `aboycott`, `a(boycott)?(boy)?`. Or, you can use `a(?:boy(?:cott)?)?`.

Comment: @m0skit0 `?` matches `zero or one`

Comment: You want the first optional capture group to be explicitly loose (lazy) by using double question marks: `a(boy)??(boycott)?`